# IntentService is not called

Tags: android, intentservice

I want to consume an IntentService for my app to laod data from server in the background thread without intracting with or disturbing application activities.
here is my simple IntentService

```
public class SearchService extends IntentService  {

    public SearchService() {
    super("SearchService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Tag","service started");
    }
```

}

i start this service in the main Activity of my application

```
public class ChannelsActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this , SearchService.class);
            startService(intent);   
         }
```

I also define service attribute in manifest file but it does't work for me i don't know what is the problem

```
 <application
    <activity
        android:name=".ChannelsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".SearchService"/>

</application>
```

I am stuck with this problem any help will really helpful for me.

Comment: please always .post the logcat.

Comment: @Bhanu Kaushik thanks for your quick reply, i have not got any error or warning in logcat window

Comment: Run it with the debugger and see if it's throwing any unlogged exceptions when you try to start the service.

Comment: @Ralgha i have tried debugging and make breakpoint at appropiate point but they are not thrown by the debugger

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but have you checked to make sure your logcat window is not filtering out debug logs?

Comment: Try an intent with an action set.  IntentServices are meant to process actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted should work. Do you see the debug log "service started" in the logcat window? Although it sounds stupid, the SearchService will run and immediately will shut down because there is no extensive work to do and you will not see the Service in Running Services if that is your goal.

Hope it helps.